# Настройка яндекс коллекций в yandex share

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Как сделать, что-бы в блоке поделиться, в *Яндекс* коллекции, добавлялось несколько изображений со страницы? Пробовал указывать изображения через запятую, в параметре `data-image:collections`, но не работает.

```
<div data-image:collections="https://site.ru/image1.jpeg, https://site.ru/image2.jpeg" data-title="Title" data-description="Description" data-image="https://site.ru/image1.jpeg"  class="ya-share2" data-limit="14" data-services="vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki,collections,gplus,tumblr,pocket,viber,whatsapp,skype,telegram,twitter,blogger,lj,delicious,digg,moimir,reddit,evernote,linkedin,qzone,renren,sinaWeibo,surfingbird,tencentWeibo" data-size="m"></div>
```

Если вообще не указывать атрибуты `data-image:collections` и `data-image`, он берет все изображения, которые есть на странице для добавления в коллекцию, но мне надо что-бы он брал только те, что я укажу.

Comment: Добавьте ваш код, который показывает как вы указываете ваши изображения. Наверняка ошибка там

Comment: <div data-image:collections="https://site.ru/image1.jpeg, https://site.ru/image2.jpeg" data-title="Title" data-description="Description" data-image="https://site.ru/image1.jpeg"  class="ya-share2" data-limit="14" data-services="vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki,collections,gplus" data-size="m"></div>